# How would this Breadth-First-Search be converted into a static method in Java?

Tags: java, python, search, breadth-first-search

I wrote this static method in Python to do breadth first search. However, I mainly use Java, and I want to get a sense of how the data structures convert to Java, given generics, etc. My code is:

```
def bfs(graph, start_vertex, target_value):
  path = [start_vertex] #a list that contains start_vertex
  vertex_and_path = [start_vertex, path] #a list that contains start_vertex and path
  bfs_queue = [vertex_and_path]
  visited = set() #visited defined as an empty set

  while bfs_queue: #while the queue is not empty
    current_vertex, path = bfs_queue.pop(0) #removes element from queue and sets both equal to that first element
    visited.add(current_vertex) #adds current vertex to visited list

    for neighbor in graph[current_vertex]: #looks at all neighboring vertices
      if neighbor not in visited: #if neighbor is not in visited list
        if neighbor is target_value: #if it's the target value
          return path + [neighbor] #returns path with neighbor appended
        else:
          bfs_queue.append([neighbor, path + [neighbor]]) #recursive call with path that has neighbor appended
```

a graph I'd use this on would be:

```
myGraph = { //I'm not sure how to structure this in Java
    'lava': set(['sharks', 'piranhas']),
    'sharks': set(['lava', 'bees', 'lasers']),
    'piranhas': set(['lava', 'crocodiles']),
    'bees': set(['sharks']),
    'lasers': set(['sharks', 'crocodiles']),
    'crocodiles': set(['piranhas', 'lasers'])
  }
```

and I would call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(bfs(myGraph, "crocodiles", "bees"));
}
```

So far, here's the Java I have:

```
    public class BreadthFirstSearch{

    ///NOT DONE YET
    public static ArrayList<String> BFS(Map<String, String[]> graph, String start, String target) {
            List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
            path.add(start);
            List<String> vertexAndPath = new ArrayList<>();
            vertexAndPath.add(start);
            vertexAndPath.add(path.get(0));
            ArrayList<String> queue = new ArrayList<>();
            queue.add(vertexAndPath.get(0));
            queue.add(vertexAndPath.get(1));
            Set<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();
            while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                String currentVertex = queue.remove(0);
                String curVerValue = currentVertex;
                path.add(currentVertex);
                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It may also help to post what your desired outcome of this is.  I'm not terribly well versed in python, so I _think_ I know what it's doing, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @CodyKnapp it should be some representation of a path that is similar to the Python output: `['crocodiles', 'lasers', 'sharks', 'bees']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good effort on the translation. Let me offer my code, then an explanation:

```
import java.util.*;

class BreadthFirstSearch {
    public static ArrayList<String> BFS(
        Map<String, String[]> graph, String start, String target
    ) {
        Map<String, String> visited = new HashMap<>();
        visited.put(start, null);
        ArrayDeque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        deque.offer(start);

        while (!deque.isEmpty()) {
            String curr = deque.poll();

            if (curr.equals(target)) {
                ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
                path.add(curr);

                while (visited.get(curr) != null) {
                    curr = visited.get(curr);
                    path.add(curr);
                }

                Collections.reverse(path);
                return path;
            }

            for (String neighbor : graph.get(curr)) {
                if (!visited.containsKey(neighbor)) {
                    visited.put(neighbor, curr);
                    deque.offer(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String[]> myGraph = new HashMap<>();
        myGraph.put(
            "lava", new String[] {"sharks", "piranhas"}
        );
        myGraph.put(
            "sharks", new String[] {"lava", "bees", "lasers"}
        );
        myGraph.put(
            "piranhas", new String[] {"lava", "crocodiles"}
        );
        myGraph.put(
            "bees", new String[] {"sharks"}
        );
        myGraph.put(
            "lasers", new String[] {"sharks", "crocodiles"}
        );
        myGraph.put(
            "crocodiles", new String[] {"piranhas", "lasers"}
        );
        System.out.println(BFS(myGraph, "crocodiles", "bees"));
        System.out.println(BFS(myGraph, "crocodiles", "crocodiles"));
        System.out.println(BFS(myGraph, "crocodiles", "zebras"));
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
[crocodiles, lasers, sharks, bees]
[crocodiles]
null
```

---

### Explanation

I made the design decision to avoid copying a `path` ArrayList on every node in the graph in favor of a `visited` hash that stores nodes in `childNode => parentNode` pairs. This way, once I've located the destination node, I retrace my steps to create the path in one shot, instead of building a path for every node, most of which ultimately lead nowhere. This is more efficient in space and time; Python makes it too easy to ruin your time complexity with the `[] + []` O(n) list concatenation operator.

Using a `child => parent` `visited` HashMap is also simpler to code in Java, which doesn't have a light weight `Pair`/`Tuple`/`struct` that can conveniently store different types as nodes in the queue. To do what you're doing in Python in passing a 2-element list into the queue, you'd either have to write your own `Pair` class, use two ArrayDeques, or avoid generics and use casting, all of which are ugly (especially the last, which is also unsafe).

Another issue I noticed in your code is usage of an ArrayList as a queue. Insertion and removal on the front of a list is a O(n) operation as all elements in the list must be shifted forward or backward in the underlying array to maintain sequencing. The optimal queue structure in Java is an [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), which offers O(1) add and removal at both ends and is not thread safe, unlike the [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) collection.

Similarly, in Python, you'll find performance is best using the [deque collection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which offers a fast `popleft` operation for all your queuing needs. Additionally, in your Python implementation, each key in your hash points to a `set`, which is okay, but seems like an unnecessary structure when a list would do (you've switched to a primitive array in Java). If you're not manipulating the graph and only iterating over neighbors, this seems ideal.

Note that this code also presumes that every node has a key in the hash that represents the graph, as your input does. If you plan to input graphs where nodes may not have keys in the hash, you'll want to make sure that `graph.get(curr)` is wrapped with a `containsKey` check to avoid crashing.

Another assumption worth mentioning: ensure your graph doesn't contain `null`s since the `visited` hash relies on `null` to indicate that a child has no parent and is the start of the search.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a separate class to hold nodes of a  graph. Those nodes could not be static, as they all have unique vertexes. From there the rest is very similar.

```
public class Node {
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Node> vertices;
    public void addEdge(Node node) {
        edges.add(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no way to replicate the `myGraph` structure in a close to identical way??